# Proposal for question staging area

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, site-recommendation

**Background**

I have been on Stack Overflow for a while now and have enjoyed it both for asking and answering questions, but of late (probably the last 1-2 years) have seen it descend more and more into minutiae about broken compiles, 'small' questions that seem to be asked because of the impression that it is easier to have someone else answer the question than to sometimes just Google the words in my question and find the answer, yes a lot of times even on Stack Overflow. Also I have seen a lot of judgment questions being closed as 'off-topic', which I know is the current policy, but for me was always a huge benefit of stack overflow. The possibility to access a large number of peoples' opinions (yes opinions) about the same thing I am trying to do. Having other peoples' opinions helps me save a lot of time making up my own mind on things. I don't know about other people but for me personally the usefulness of Stack Overflow has decreased, both as a research tool for asking, but also as a place to answer questions.

**Problem**

There are a quite a few sites out there that have if not somewhat overlapping then at least related concerns, with Stack Overflow, Programmers, Super User, Game Development, Programming Puzzles and Code Golf, etc., I think it has become harder and harder (especially for novice users) to find the right website for the right question, as these sites have become stricter and stricter with their question policies it becomes harder and harder for users to post questions there. As the number of sites increases it becomes harder and harder to find the correct site for a question.

**Solution**

Why not create a staging area for questions where reviewers can funnel the question into the correct site, using users reputation for a specific site as a filter whether to allow a user to directly post to a site or to force them to use the staging area. The benefits would be on both sides of the fence for the askers a higher chance of finding an answer and for the answering side better focus of question in the specific sites.

**Caveats & Other Thoughts**

I did not investigate the other sites as much, as I know Stack Overflow, and I am not such a part of the community to know whether this is even feasible or if the other sites have similar problems. Basically some of the specialization of the site is just a matter of 'tagging' a question correctly considering all the IT and software development related questions the differentiation between a game-development and a super user question could be made by using an appropriate tag.

I am sure some of these issues have already been discussed, so if this an idea that has already been talked through and is considered not feasible, I apologize. Also personally I wish we could find a place for opinion questions, i think they provide a lot more value than a large part of the fact based question because they access peoples experience, which is personal, but usually is not explicit.

Comment: Who would actually spend time there routing questions?   What's wrong with allowing users to make their best guess, and then offering suggestions for the best site in the comments?  That seems to work pretty well in practice, if the community allows deletion/reposting to the correct site rather than the arduous process of mod migration.

Comment: Sounds a bit like this [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233483/could-there-be-an-i-dont-know-what-forum-to-post-this-in-meta-site-kind-of/233489#233489) question I answered a couple months back

Comment: I think the time spent routing questions would be offset by time that used to be spent closing questions

Comment: Ultimately, it's the responsibility of the asker to put in the necessary work to figure out where their question goes.

Comment: If that were made into a queue, it would be huge. Think about how many questions from low rep users are asked every day.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm not mistaken Meta is the place to ask questions about which site to post on.

Both [Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) and [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) have a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag for users who are unsure of where to post their question.

**From the site-recommendation tag wiki & excerpt:**

> Don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network?
>   Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask,
>   and the community will help you find the appropriate site.
>
> With the vast openness of the Stack Exchange Network, it can sometimes
>   be confusing where exactly a question is supposed to go. If you are
>   unsure after reading site FAQs, or if you cannot find an existing
>   question here on Meta, consider asking a new question with this tag.

Though I would guess, and it definitely looks like, site recommendations are better suited for and are better received on Meta SE.